# android- implementing ListVIew in Fragment using Base adapter , what am i doing wrong?

Tags: android, listview, fragment, baseadapter

**Problem Sloverd, i was trying to implement listview in a fragment without implenting listfragment**

> (just extends fragment)

**and A custom adapter without extending any ArrayAdapter or ListAdapter**..

> (just extends BaseAdapter)

My following code is showing no error but listview is not showing in the fragment. I am using a custom adapter to show two edittext together. during debugging i can see adapter sending a list in the view but listview.setadapter() not binding any data  Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? i have tried to find similar solution here but no luck. I would greatly appreciate any feedback or pointing to a similar problem like this . **Fragment:**

```
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;    
    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class ResultFragment extends Fragment {
        private DBHelper dbHelper=null;
        ArrayList<MedicineModel> medicineModelList=new ArrayList<MedicineModel>();
        String selectedData="";
        CustomAdapterBrandResult adapter;
        ListView listView;

        public ResultFragment() {
        }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, container, false);

            listView= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultList);
            TextView textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.selected_text);

            Bundle bundle=getArguments();
            if(bundle!=null){
                textView.setText(bundle.getString("selected_data"));
                selectedData=(bundle.getString("selected_data"));
            }

            dbHelper=new DBHelper(this.getActivity());
            medicineModelList=  dbHelper.getAllUsingBrandName(selectedData);

            adapter=new CustomAdapterBrandResult(getActivity(),  medicineModelList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return view;
        }

    }
```

**Custom Adapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapterBrandResult extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mcontext;
    private ArrayList<MedicineModel> medicineModelList;
    public CustomAdapterBrandResult(Context mcontext, ArrayList<MedicineModel> medicineModelList) {
        this.mcontext = mcontext;
        this.medicineModelList = medicineModelList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return medicineModelList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return medicineModelList.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view=View.inflate(mcontext,R.layout.custom_layout_brand_result,null);

        final TextView textViewBrand=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2BrandName);
        final TextView textViewManufacture=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3Manufacture);

        textViewBrand.setText( medicineModelList.get(position).getBrandName());
        textViewManufacture.setText(medicineModelList.get(position).getNameoftheManufacturer());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally! able to show the listview in my fragment.Added  override onCreate method and intialized list and adpater there and in the override onCreateView method just set the adapter on the listview,that is it..working per perfactly fine. Thanks to the guys ,

@IntelliJAmiya and
@Mikerizzo
who comment on my question and spent their time to examine it

**Here is the final solution : Fragment**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null){

            selectedData=(bundle.getString("selected_data"));
        }

        dbHelper=new DBHelper(this.getActivity());
        medicineModelList=  dbHelper.getAllUsingBrandName(selectedData);
        adapter=new CustomAdapterBrandResult(getActivity(),  medicineModelList);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, container, false);


        listView= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultList);
        TextView textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.selected_text);
        textView.setText(selectedData);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


 //       int a = listView.getAdapter().getCount();



        return view;
    }
```

Comment: @Mikerizzo   solved it finally but still, don't know why I have to separate those. anyways thank you bro

Comment: @IntelliJA thanks for the time, truly appreciate it :) and see the solution, you were right, sloppy mistake...haha